# Weblogic - SESSIONS_PER_USER limit

Tags: oracle, weblogic

I am using Weblogic 10.3.6 with Oracle DB. I am using the default jdbc jars that come with Weblogic for the connection. Right now we have 8 servers using the same database resource. We keep getting the following error after running for a while:

ORA-02391: exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit

I am unfamiliar with Weblogic settings. Which one should I change (if any) to help get rid of this error. I understand our DBA could increase the sessions limit but that is not what we want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your JDBC resource in the Weblogic admin console. You will want to check the following values on the Connection Pool tab:

`Initial Capacity`

`Maximum Capacity`

If you have 8 servers using the same JDBC resource, they may all be bumping up against the Max Capacity for the pool and I am guessing 8xMaxCapacity is greater than your configured sessions limit. Try dropping the max to see if that resolves the issue.